# Would relay with temporary keys live the same great as with constant keys?

Tags: relays

I'm on Debian-like OS.

Directory `/var/lib/tor/keys/` contains `secret_id_key` and `secret_onion_key` RSA keys.

Would my relay work the same with **5Mb/s** of bandwidth if I remove these keys each reboot, simply by `/etc/rc.local` ?

```
rm /var/lib/tor/keys/*
service tor restart
```

Say, I will start the relay fresh each time I boot. Am I losing any bounties from network like guard, etc...?

Will my bandwidth been used in the past be the same? E.g. When rebooting everyday.
Or does warming-up of a new relay required more than 7 days?

Should I clean anything else?

Comment: "Or warming-up of new relay required more than 7 days?" I'm not sure what this should say, so I did not mess with it.

Comment: "Warming-up" means pass all of bandwidth's and guard's test embedded into Tor code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I modified the question in regards to the meaning of that part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The blog post »[The lifecycle of a new relay](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay)« is helpful for your question:

> A new relay, assuming it is reliable and has plenty of bandwidth, goes through four phases: the unmeasured phase (days 0-3) where it gets roughly no use, the remote-measurement phase (days 3-8) where load starts to increase, the ramp-up guard phase (days 8-68) where load counterintuitively drops and then rises higher, and the steady-state guard phase (days 68+).

So if you reboot every day and remove the keys on this basis your relay is a new relay after every reboot. So initially you will see a low amount of traffic. While you can do some steps to improve this, I guess this relay will not be very helpful for the network as a whole.

Furthermore there is quite a good chance that somebody notices the high rate of key rotation. I guess this will raise some questions and maybe lead to the fact that some people will distrust your relay.